# how to copy the numberformat of a listobject to another listobject in VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I want to fectch the numberformats from one listobject and apply it to another listobject in VSTO .

I tried using the approach :

```
for(int i=1 ;i<=sourceListObject.listcolumns.count;i++)
{
listobject1.listcolumns.item[i].range.numberformat  = sourceListObject.listcolumns.item[i].range.numberformat
}
```

but this didnt work .. as in the numberformats were not applied to listobject1.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to copy number format on column-by-column basis. This would work only if all cells in each column had the same numberformat, [otherwise NumberFormat Property returns null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.numberformat%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

You should probably do it cell-by-cell (`ListObject.Range.get_Item(1,1)` is the first cell in the ListObject).